# Max retries exceeded with url Selenium webdriver When integrating Gym and stable-baselines

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am using Selenium Webdriver using python in orther to do several actions over a web page using a RL model. I have successfully trained the said model, but when trying to actually used the already trained model, I am getting this error:

`urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=53095): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2ed30e3c902b7aee22de7b6072cfd3fd/source (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f361a8083d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`
I have made a summary of my code to see when the driver is being used, but I am not able to find the reason why the driver seems to work fine until a certain point, as I am not requesting many URLs at the same time nor retrying to get a certain URL. This is my code:

**main.py:**

```
driver = utils.initializeBrowser()
driver.get(some_url)
res = utils.login(driver, force = True)

agent = Agent( MyEnv.v1(driver))

source = driver.page_source # This is when the error happens
```

**utils.py:**

```
def initializeBrowser():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--auto-show-cursor')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    print("Intializing default Chromedriver")
    return webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

def login(driver, force = False):
    current_url = driver.current_url 
    print(current_url)
    driver.save_screenshot(f"../img/before-login.png")
    username_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name*="user"]')
    username_input.clear()
            
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name*="password"]')
    password_input.clear()
    # More opertations to click and write on those inputs...
```

**MyEnv**:

```
def __init__(self, driver = None):
    super().__init__()
    # Other setup ....
    self.driver = driver
    if driver:
        # Url and before taking the action
        self.url_start = driver.current_url
        self.obs_start = self._get_observation()
        self.visited_urls = [self.driver.current_url]

def restore(self, state_dict, verbose = True):
    # Additional code not related to the driver...
    driver = utils.initializeBrowser()
    utils.login(driver)
    if self.url_end:
        try:
            driver.get(self.url_end)
        except:
            driver.get(env['URL'])
    else:
        driver.get(env['URL'])
    self.driver = driver
```

**Agent:**

```
def __init__(self, gym_env = None):
    # Additional code ... 
    load_path = "/path/to/the/model"
    self.model = self.model_type.load(load_path, env = self.env , custom_objects={"observation_space": self.env.observation_space, "action_space": self.env.action_space})
    env_backup_file = f"path/to/file.pickle"
    with open(env_backup_file, 'rb') as file:
        backup_data = pickle.load(file)
        self.env = MyEnv.v1(driver)
        self.env.restore(backup_data)
        self.model.set_env(self.env)
```